# Implementing caching using a spring bean

Tags: spring, caching, singleton, javabeans

I want to implement caching in my java spring project. My cache object is updated through a method using spring trigger. I am aware that spring allows the ehcache and the java concurrenthashmap for caching. My question is , cant we just define a spring bean (which by default is singleton). Update the spring bean in regular intervals. The spring bean will be read only for the requests that read out of the cache? Could you please let me know if this way of implementing a cache will work ?